# Python Run selenium Chrome with proxy

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm struggling trying to get Selenium with chrome to work with a proxy. I have tried the Selenium documentation and tried to alter it for chrome but I get errors after the browser launches. I'm using PyCharm

I read that chrome.options has changed to absolute path now in the newest version.

I tried this, it runs through goes to the web page but does not show an IP change. I tried a few proxies I know work and the same thing

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  
PROXY = "111.111.111.109:15001" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT # not actual proxy ip.

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm astounded that there's not a simple solution to this, you would think having the capability of using proxies in a test browser would be part of it core?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you specify URL scheme too:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  
PROXY = "111.111.111.109:15001" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT # not actual proxy ip.

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=https://%s' % PROXY)

chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: I tried that and it still shows my home IP address in the browser

Answer (score 0):

This works with my provider anyway. '--proxy-server=***https://%s' %*** PROXY) was screwing it up

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    proxy = '163.000.48.000:15001'
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=' + proxy)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```